# Blender 2.8 Crash on selecting Look Dev

Tags: 3d-view

**UPDATE**
Updating the Graphics Driver has solved this. Thanks.

I downloaded Blender 2.8 (blender-2.80-windows64) just now.

Started it with a simple cube.

Clicked on Look Dev & it crashed. Does this every time Look Dev is clicked.

System Info:

[image]

Graphics Info (Intel(R) HD 4000:

[image: GPU Info]

**Updated GPU Info**
[image]

Any other info I can provide?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: What graphics card (GPU) are you using?

Comment: I also have the same issue as my GPU is incompatible with eevee. Check the compatibility of your GPU with eevee.